How to add headers to API (httpClient) in ANGULAR
I am trying to add headers to my API as follows,
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.headers = headers.set('test', 'test-headers');
  }

getInitialData(q: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<InitialResponse>(`${this.serverUrl}/getInitialData?` + query, this.headers).toPromise();
  }

When I check in the network tab, I am not able to see the header 'test'. what am I missing here?

Try passing it inside as a property of an object as the second argument
Angular http client docs
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.headers = headers.set('test', 'test-headers');
  }

getInitialData(q: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<InitialResponse>(`${this.serverUrl}/getInitialData?` + query, { headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
  }


Try to use this way :
OPTIONS: {
  headers: {
    'test': 'test-headers',
  }
}

getInitialData(q: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<InitialResponse>(`${this.serverUrl}/getInitialData?` + query,this.OPTIONS).toPromise();
  }

